# Is it possible to assign a Plugin, a timer, which would cause the Plugin to deactivate upon the time being reached?

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I currently have an activated 3rd Party Plugin.  Is it possible to add some kind of coding, which would deactivate the Plugin on a set date/time?  Maybe even set a countdown timer?

I have looked in the Plugin itself and there is no option.

I know this is a broad question.  I have never come across such a feature but would welcome any directives on a possible solution.

I have complete access to the server too, so maybe there is a way to implement some kind of feature, on the server/web files, which would delete the Plugin files after a certain period?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`wp_schedule_event`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_schedule_event) or add a cron job to run your script.

Script would be something like this:

```
if($datetime > $expire_datetime) {
    $my_plugin = $plugin_path.'my_plugin/my_plugin.php';
    // Check to see if plugin is already active
    if(is_plugin_active($my_plugin)) {
        deactivate_plugins($my_plugin);
    }
}
```

Take a look at [`deactivate_plugins`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/deactivate_plugins) function too.